# mpld3 produces axes property value that cannot be serialized to JSON

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5, mpld3

I am doing a scatter plot using `matplotlib` and trying to use `mpld3` to plot it in HTML. The `figure` when converted to dict, produces a property `edgewidths` with value type array with single element of value `1.` which `json.dumps` cannot serialize to a JSON type. I am not sure which `matplotlib` `axes` property I need to change to fix this issue or do any of these libraries need some initialization properties set? Also is `mpld3` the best backend for rendering as HTML?

*Sample code*

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.scatter(a, b)

fig_json = json.dumps(mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig), skipkeys=True)
```

*Problematic dict property when pretty printing dict*

```
{'axes': [{'axes': [{'fontsize': 10.0,
                 'grid': {'alpha': 1.0,
                          'color': '#D3D3D3',
 ...
        'axesbgalpha': None,
 ...
       'collections': [{'alphas': [None],
 ...
                        'edgewidths': array([1.]), <--- This property
```

*Exception*

```
fig_json = json.dumps(mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig), skipkeys=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
 **kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
 return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
 raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: array([1.]) is not JSON serializable
```

*Dependencies used*

- matplotlib (2.1.2)
- mpld3 (0.3)

Comment: This seems to be a mpld3 problem. Check [this Github issue](https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/434).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the GitHub issue. Looks like the fix has went in to the repo but it is not part of a new release. Also it is mentioned there that mpld3 is not supported actively anymore. I have decided to move on to `bokeh` as matplotlib/mpld3 replacement.